# Should I have redundant method names between related classes?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, dry, encapsulation

I'm building a sports product. I have 3 classes

```
class Team {
  getName // ex: Los Angeles Lakers
  getShortName // ex: Lakers
  getAbbrName // ex: LAL
}

class Match {
  Team getHomeTeam
  Team getAwayTeam
  Play[] plays
}

class Play {
  Match getMatch
  String description // "Kobe Bryant scores a 3 pointer!"
}
```

A team is just any sports team. A match is a sports match between two teams. During a match, plays happen that get attached to that match.

I have the need to get the home/away team's name, short name, and abbreviated names, given a `Match` or `Play`. Which option do you prefer and why?

Option 1 - callers need to do this. Ex:

```
class SomeCaller {
  foo() {
     Play play = // somehow get a play;
     Match match = play->getMatch;
     Team home = match->getHomeTeam;
     Team away = match->getAwayTeam;
     String homeTeamName = home->getName;
     String homeTeamShortName = home->getShortName;
     String homeTeamAbbrName = home->getAbbrName;
     String awayTeamName = away->getName;
     String awayTeamShortName = away->getShortName;
     String awayTeamAbbrName = away->getAbbrName;
     // do something with the team names
  }
}
```

Option 2 - Add the same methods to both classes

```
class Match {
  Team getHomeTeam
  Team getAwayTeam
  Play[] plays

  String getHomeTeamName() {
    Team homeTeam = getHomeTeam();
    return homeTeam->getName();
  }

  // same as above...
  String getHomeTeamShortName()
  String getHomeTeamAbbrName()
  String getAwayTeamName()
  String getAwayTeamShortName()
  String getAwayTeamAbbrName()
}

class Play {
  Match getMatch

  String getHomeTeamName() {
    Match match = getMatch;
    return match->getHomeTeamName();
  }

  // same as above...
  String getHomeTeamShortName()
  String getHomeTeamAbbrName()
  String getAwayTeamName()
  String getAwayTeamShortName()
  String getAwayTeamAbbrName()
}
```

Keep in mind I would want to get name, short name, abbr name, for both home and away teams given a Match or Play object, so there's going to be lots of method duplication with option 2.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 is prefered of the two. 
Typically you wouldn't have a reference from Play to Match and Match to Play.

```
class Team {
  getName // ex: Los Angeles Lakers
  getShortName // ex: Lakers
  getAbbrName // ex: LAL
}

class Match {
  Team getHomeTeam
  Team getAwayTeam
  Play[] plays
}

class Play {
  String description // "Kobe Bryant scores a 3 pointer!"
}
```

Now, you won't be able to get the team names with only a Play, but if you have access to all the matches you can do something like this:

```
foreach(match in matches)
    foreach(play in match)
        if(play == desiredPlay)
            doSomething
```

If this isn't acceptable, in case you need to get team names from only a play, without knowing the matches, you would have a reference to this directly in your play. I.e:

```
class Play {
  Team getHomeTeam
  Team getAwayTeam
  String description // "Kobe Bryant scores a 3 pointer!"
}
```

This couples your code more than option 2, but less than option 1.

This is all because of "Law of Demeter" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) which in a nutshell says, you shouldn't know of the Match, if it is what Match knows you really want, you should instead know of Team.

The link has a decent example I suggest you read. :)